# В каком числе ставить глагол?

Tags: согласование

В каком числе нужно ставить глагол в данном случае:

> После двух-трех попыток стало очевидно, что леска или удочка не
>   (выдержит/выдержат).

И почему так, а не иначе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тогда уж *леска или удилище*.
Раз у вас "или", лучше написать "не выдержит". Сравните: *После двух-трех попыток стало очевидно, что леска и удилище не выдержат.*

Comment: Лучше или правильнее? Я бы хотел определить, как будет "правильнее". Должны же быть правила согласования. Вот только что-то найти их я не могу.

Comment: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь разобрался.